# Returning Structure from Function Implementation

Tags: c, compiler-construction, struct

In C and C++ we can return structures or classes from functions and methods:

```
class A final { public:
    int i;
    A(int n) { this->i=n; }
};
A function(void) {
    return A(4);
}
int main(void) {
    A result = function();
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to know is how is this implemented?  The traditional wisdom is that it is copied, thus incurring a cost: to mitigate, you can pass a pointer to the structure instead and return nothing.

However, I'm not sure that this is (always) necessary.  In the above, for example, the constructed structure was never used locally.  Since we're returning it, couldn't the data be instead filled into the `result` variable one level higher directly, before the stack is popped?

The main problem to doing this, as I see it, is that the callee function needs to know where the caller wants the result.  Another problem is in the case of more recursive functions: if the ultimate variable you're copying into is several layers higher in the stack, then it would become much harder for the callee to locate the correct place.  My guess, based on my limited compiler knowledge, is that it is instead the *caller* that copies the struct *from* the callee, right after the return.

In general, I feel like such an optimization might be tricky.  For inlined functions, I expect it to happen implicitly, and if the structure is never used locally, I can't see a reason why it couldn't be implemented this way.  However, for everything else, I expect the issues you run into trying to implement it are too great, and indeed in general it is just copied.

So:

- inline: (happens implicitly?)
- return never-used new structure: (happens?)
- recursive: (any complications?)
- in general: (doesn't happen?)

Comment: The code is C++, not valid in C. Use the correct tag.

Comment: In C++ it probably just constructs a single object in `result`. The feature that allows this is called *copy elision*. Your object still has to have a valid copy-constructor or move-constructor but the compiler can choose to skip it. You cannot force copy-elision to happen, your compiler has the final say on what optimization decisions it makes.

Comment: @YuHao as I wrote, "In C and C++ we can return structures or classes".  The question concerns both languages.  My example is C++, as I felt it would be more clear.  However, I picked C as the tag because the question ultimately boils down to a C feature--and I didn't add both tags because I thought it would be redundant.

Comment: @IanMallett I notices that, that's why I left a comment instead of editing your question. I think it's best to be consistent, C code with C tag, or C++ code with C++ tag. Even in the seemingly common places, there are many differences between the two languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, compilers often use the [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) idiom (often called " return value optimization") to avoid unnecessary copies when returning values. At least, they are often *allowed* to do it.

C++ Standard, section § 12.8 :

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor
>   selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the
>   object have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the
>   source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two
>   different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of
>   that object occurs at the later of the times when the two objects
>   would have been destroyed without the optimization.
>
> This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is
>   permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to
>   eliminate multiple copies)
>
> - **In a return statement in a function** with a class return type, when the
>     expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than
>     a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv- unqualified
>     type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be
>     omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the
>     function’s return value
> - ...